# convert utc time into local time using vb.net

Tags: datetime, vb.net-2010, utc

Using vb.net am trying to convert utc time to local time .but i think am getting the wrong result. Here i enclosed mycode.

```
code

Dim time As DateTime = New DateTime()
time = Date.FromFileTimeUtc(1344502618)
MsgBox(time)


getting result like this

1/1/1601 12:02:14 AM
```

is this result is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write

```
Dim time As Double = Convert.ToDouble(1344502618)
    Dim baseDate As New Date()
    Dim result As Date = baseDate.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time))
    MsgBox(result)
```